# drop down created with space

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have beeen trying hard to place a drop down menu and finally i am sucessfull. But still i have another issue. The problem is a small gap is created between the text box and the drop down image. Here is my html code. Can anyone please help me to identify the issue.

```
<input type="text" id="DropDownTextBox" readonly="true" 
    style="height:17px;font:normal 10px verdana;
     width:85px;border-right:0px ;
     border-bottom:1px solid #333;
     border-top:1px solid #333;
     border-left:1px solid #333;"
     value ='Filter' 
     onClick="ShowDropDown('DropDownTextBox');"/>
 <img src="/images/dropdown_arrow.png"
     style="vertical-align:middle;"
     onClick="ShowDropDown('DropDownTextBox');"
     id="showDropDownImg"/>
```

Comment: hey, try to use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to post your sample. So, it's easier for us to see.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle output:
http://jsfiddle.net/RhtSA/embedded/result/

Comment: Also this : http://jsfiddle.net/RhtSA/

Answer (score 1):

You Just Need to remove/delete the space between img tag starting and input tag ending. see below and execute it, now you will not find any space in between.

```
    <input type="text" id="DropDownTextBox" readonly="true" 
style="height:17px;font:normal 10px verdana; width:85px;border-right:0px ;border-bottom:1px solid #333;border-top:1px solid #333;border-left:1px solid #333;" value ='Filter' onClick="ShowDropDown('DropDownTextBox');"/>
<img src="/images/dropdown_arrow.png" 
style="vertical-align:middle;" onClick="ShowDropDown('DropDownTextBox');" id="showDropDownImg"/>
```

Comment: HTML does not take into account of spaces between tags.see this :- http://jsfiddle.net/CaCLt/

Comment: @Pranav -- HTML doesn't care about _how many_ whitespace characters there are, but if there are more than zero, whitespace will appear in the output: http://jsfiddle.net/JWCzy/

Comment: and hence they were appearing as space between the tags....I have executed it and replied accordingly

Comment: @Pranav Just have look into my profile page and see my Real Name.. you might like it.... :)

Comment: @OMTheEternity:-... Pranav... +1 for you..:P

Comment: @Pranav Thanks Mirror Name :)